# Remove all events from HTML Element and its child using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have unknown HTML that may be changed each time page load, that it is being retrieved from an API.

How can i remove all events from it ?

html :

```
 <div id="content">
        <h2 onclick="alert('hi');">Test 1</h2>
        <div onmouseover="alert('hi')">Test 2</div>
 </div>
```

I want it to be

```
<div id="content">
            <h2>Test 1</h2>
            <div>Test 2</div>
</div>
```

I already searched and found a solution but it doesn't work for me

```
var el = document.getElementById('content'),
    elClone = el.cloneNode(true);

el.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
```

the `elClone` element still contains events. How can i remove all events from a given html block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove on attributes with something like this:

```js
function removeOnAttributes(element) 
{
  for (var attribute of element.attributes) 
    if (/^on/i.test(attribute.name)) 
      element.removeAttribute(attribute.name);

  for (var element of element.children) 
    removeOnAttributes(element);
}

removeOnAttributes( content );

content.outerHTML = content.outerHTML; // to remove the other non-atribute event handlers

console.log( content.outerHTML );
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <h2 onclick="alert('hi');">Test 1</h2>
        <div onmouseover="alert('hi')">Test 2</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Worked , Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question right, you want a function in your JavaScript to turn this:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2 onclick="alert('hi');">Test 1</h2>
    <div onmouseover="alert('hi')">Test 2</div>
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Test 1</h2>
    <div>Test 2</div>
</div>
```

All you have to do is this:

First add IDs to your elements (e.g. `id="test1"` and `id="test2"`)

```
function funcname() {
    document.getElementById("test1").removeAttribute("onclick");
    document.getELementById("test2").removeAttribute("onmouseover");
}
```

Then call your function when you want to, and you're set!

Even if you don't want to do it the way I did, all you need is the `removeAttribute();` function.

Comment: No man , the HTML is unknown , i don't know if it will have onclick or onmouseover , i want to remove all events from HTML Block

Answer (score 0):

You said the response came from an API and you append it to the html.
You can have a look at the [CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) it might suit your case, you can entirely remove inline scripts.

Either way, there are also parsers that can do that for you I believe.

Take a look at https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-caja/wikis/JsHtmlSanitizer.wiki